# uPNP - handling changes to local IP address

Tags: upnp

I boot my laptop w/o a LAN connection and get the link-local address 169.254.1.1

My local uPNP clients/servers start discovering one another and communicating.

Now I connect to my LAN and DHCP assigns me a proper routable IP address 10.0.0.4.

I would like my uPNP clients and servers to start interacting with others over the LAN.

Do all my clients and servers need to be written to detect this situation and restart their uPNP sessions or is there a better way? For example, is there a uPNP s/w libary that supports IP address changes internally?

thanks,

r

Answer (score 1):

[ohNet](http://wiki.openhome.org/wiki/OhNet) will detect changes in IP address and update devices, including switching them between network interfaces.  Its a C++ library with bindings for C#, Java and C clients.  It is liberally licensed and has ports available for desktop and mobile platforms.

Disclaimer: I'm not entirely unbiased here - I maintain the project.

Comment: Thanks. Can you link to any details on this support?

Comment: Do you mean "are there docs on this subject"?  The answer to that is "no" - handling of IP changes is internal to the library.  It Just Works so doesn't need to be visible to client code :-)